# When select emoji message gets instantly sent instead of waiting for clicking send button

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

We are using this library https://github.com/ahkohd/ngx-emoji-picker
to implement emojis in our chat. The problem is that when you select emoji from the picker it sends message instantly and doesn't let to continue typing message and clicking send button. Here is the code:

```
SendMessage() {
    if (this.message) {
      console.log('ts', this.receiverData.username);
      this.msgService
        .SendMessage(this.user._id, this.receiverData._id, this.receiverData.username, this.message)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.socket.emit('refresh', {});
          this.message = '';
        });
    }
  }

  handleSelection(event) {
    console.log(event.char);
    this.message += event.char;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="message-input">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="colinput">
                    <input [(ngModel)]="message" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                        (keypress)="IsTyping()" type="text" placeholder="Write your message..." />
                </div>
                <i class='attachment'
                (click)="toggled = !toggled"
                [(emojiPickerIf)]="toggled"
                [emojiPickerDirection]="'top'"
                (emojiPickerSelect)="handleSelection($event)"></i>
                <button class="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What can cause such an issue and how can it be fixed?

Comment: when does the `SendMessage() ` function called ?

Comment: Before adding emojis it was called when send button was clicked. Now when you select emoji it instantly gets called instead of waiting to complete other text.

Answer (score 0):

If you used (ngSubmit)="SendMessage()" in form tag , any button click inside that form will call the SendMessage method ,this might be the problem in your case .one way to avoid  that is use click event on send button

Answer (score 0):

```
class component_name implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterContentChecked {
  ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    const elements: any = document.getElementsByClassName('emoji-button');
    if (elements.length > 0) {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-for-of
      for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
          const type = 'type';
          elements[i][type] = 'button';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: don't add code into the comment, please update your answer

Comment: when we click on any emoji's the form will be automatically submitted. Instead of the, we have added button type="button" using the above code.